# Transfer Mac App Store app

Tags: sandbox, mac-app-store

I am trying to transfer an app of mine into my company iTunesConnect account but are getting the error:

```
You can't transfer this app because of the following reasons:
Sandboxed Group Container
You can only transfer sandboxed apps that are not sharing a group container.
```

the thing is, my app isn't using the group container any more, it was in an older version but not the currently shipping version in the Mac App Store.

does anyone have any experience with how to go about transferring the app?

Comment: as I know, once u have the history, you can't get rid of it. Just like subscription, if your app has subscription users before, you can't transfer the app in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Even though my app wasn't currently using a group container (it had in the past) I couldn't transfer it. I had to re-upload as a new app losing all my reviews.. :(

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be impossible. I got the following response from iTunes Connect Support (September 15, 2017):

> I have reviewed your enquiry and found that once the app has the
>   entitlement included, an app transfer will not be possible, even if
>   you submit a new version without the entitlement. However, you can
>   transfer the app via the binary reassigned process.

By completing this process (a "binary transfer"), the app will effectively be a new and separate app on the Mac App Store. This might of course be very inconvenient, but there's not really anything to do about it, unless Apple changes the rules.

Comment: what is the meaning of "binary reassigned process" ??

Comment: It essentially means creating the app again, i.e. on the new developer account
1) Create a new app id.
2) Create a whole new app in iTunes Connect using this app id.
3) Build and upload your existing app code using this new app id (and associated provisioning profile and certificate).